# I'm trying to integrate VUE.JS into ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT28X.png)[image]

I'm getting following Console Error. Error : Cannot find module

Here is the full error i'm getting in console. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Launch the command `npm run install`, if nothing change udpate your question with more details.

Comment: @Raphael Rollet I used the method you provided and got these errors. I updated in my question

Comment: In your screenshot i see the path is window/system32 you have to run it inside your project. The error say you don't have the package.json but i assume in your project you have one.

Comment: @Raphael Rollet i run it inside my project got these errors, I updated in my question

Comment: You can try to delete your file node_modules and reinstall it with the commande npm run install or yarn install